# Catching when an activity is restarted from a crash

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi I am dealing with a 3rd party library that is buggy at times and causes the activity restart. Is there a way to tell when an activity is restarted from a crash? I tried using an uncaught exception handler like this but it wasn't being triggered.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d("un", "caught");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Masking bugs is always a bad idea. Ask the library's author to address the bugs or fix them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

write like this

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(this,YOURCURRENTCLASSNAME.class));
```

And use this class dear. i also used this

```
public class MyExceptionHandler implements
        java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final Context myContext;
    private final Class<?> myActivityClass;

    public MyExceptionHandler(Context context, Class<?> c) {

        myContext = context;
        myActivityClass = c;
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {

        StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
        System.err.println(stackTrace);// You can use LogCat too
        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, myActivityClass);
        String s = stackTrace.toString();
        // you can use this String to know what caused the exception and in
        // which Activity
        intent.putExtra("uncaughtException",
                "Exception is: " + stackTrace.toString());
        intent.putExtra("stacktrace", s);
        myContext.startActivity(intent);
        // for restarting the Activity
//      Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        System.out.println("comingggggggggggggggggg in crashhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh and restrttttttttttttt autometically ");
        Intent i = myContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(myContext.getPackageName() );
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myContext.startActivity(i);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to override this and also pass the message through to the default log cat with the error coloring?

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are looking for a working-out-of-the-box solution, you can use a bug tracker service, such as [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) or [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/). They both offer a way of knowing if the current run occurred just after a crash.

**Crashlytics**

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().setListener(new CrashlyticsListener() {
    @Override
    public void crashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution() {
        // if this method is called, it means that a crash occurred
        // in the previous run
        didCrashOnLastLoad = true;
    }
});
```

**Crittercism** ([source](http://docs.crittercism.com/android/android.html#enhancing-crash-reporting))

```
CritterCallback cb = new CritterCallback() {
    @Override public void onCritterDataReceived(CritterUserData userData) {
        boolean crashedOnLastLoad = userData.crashedOnLastLoad();
        // ...do something with crashedOnLastLoad
    }
};

CritterUserDataRequest request = new CritterUserDataRequest(cb)
                               .requestDidCrashOnLastLoad();

// Fire off the request.
request.makeRequest();
```